# Как получить обычный String используя Retrofit 2?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Хочу разобраться как работает Retrofit, но документация совсем скудная([может не там смотрю](https://square.github.io/retrofit/))

Мне нужно сделать самый простой get запрос к серверу и получить ответ в виде строки.

Сейчас использую HTTPUrlConnection, но очень интересно стало все переделать под Retrofit

Подскажите, есть ли у кого то пример или туториал как получить ответ с сервера не конвертируя его в объекты на лету и все прочие, просто запрос просто ответ

Comment: Не совсем понятный вопрос. Ты имеешь ввиду получить сам JSON?

Comment: @Kostya Ну можно сказать сам Json. Как это работает у меня сейчас использованием HTTPUrlConnection я получаю response от сервера который складываю в строку и потом эту строку конвертирую в Json и делаю парс как мне нужно. Так вот с Retrofit я тоже хочу в ответе получить строку с которой буду волен делать то, что мне нужно) Конвертировать или не конвертировать и все остальное

Answer (score 2):

вам нужно пометить получаемый параметр как `ResponseBody`
например:

```
public interface Api {
    @GET()
    Call<ResponseBody> getString();
}

Call<ResponseBody> myCall = myApi.getString()
myCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(...) {
        String myString = response.body().string();
        ...
    }
    ...
});
```