# Как вытащить строку из onResponse?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, android-volley

Как сделать так, чтобы serverAnswer передавался вне onResponse?

А то получается так, что в onResponse в serverAnswer кладутся данные, но вне onResponse переменная serverAnswer пустая.

Допустим, если выводить Toast с serverAnswer в onResponse, то выведется нужный текст, а если, допустим, выводить Toast вне onResponse, то выведется пустота.

И addUser передает пустую строку.

```
public String addUser(final String username, final String email, final String password, final Context context) {

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            REGISTER_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(final String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        final JSONObject status = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Result");
                        serverAnswer = status.getString("Server answer");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    serverAnswer = error.getMessage();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
            params.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
            params.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(request);

    return serverAnswer;
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить обычный String используя Retrofit 2?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/630438/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-string-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-retrofit-2)

Answer (score 0):

У Вас **асинхронный** запрос, поэтому везде по коду, до момента выполнения запроса, `serverAnswer` будет пустой. Метод `addUser(...)` возвращает значение **до** того, как с сервера пришел ответ.

Предложу пару вариантов:

1. В метод `addUser(...)` можете передавать коллбэк:

   ```
   public interface OnRequestFinishedListener {
       void onResponse(String serverAnswer);
   }
   ```

   ```
   public void addUser(..., OnRequestFinishedListener onRequestFinishedListener) {
       ...
   }
   ```

   и после ответа сервера вызывать соответствующий метод:

   ```
   onRequestFinishedListener.onResponse(serverAnswer);
   ```
2. Можно выполнить запрос **синхронно**, но тогда придется самому возиться с созданием фонового потока, в котором будет выполняться метод.

Comment: onRequestFinishedListener.onResponse(serverAnswer);
И тогда в этом методе и передавать serverAnswer?
return ServerAnswer